# css remove an inline important from javascript loaded widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my website, I am using tawk.to

I want to ovveride its css so that the widget is not displayed when the user prints the page. However the widget container comes with an inline style "display: block !important;" which I am unable to override.

The following code does not work. Any idea?

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $_Tawk_API={},$_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/my_id/default';
        s1.charset='UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
    $(function(){
        $('#tawkchat-iframe-container').removeProp('display');
        console.log('removed'); //actually logged but the property is not removed.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Set its height to 0 - or, if you don't need the space, set it's opacity to 0 - or, set it's width to 0 - lots of options...

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Brilliant.  If none of those are an option, you can also set display with !important, and beat out the other setter on specificity.

Comment: What if you use `$('#tawkchat-iframe-container').attr('style', '');`...?

Comment: @AhsN If you remove all styles it does not default to `display: none` AFAIK

Comment: thanks ! the opacity was the solution. the widget is actually rendered with proprietary javascript and I could not override it with my own js. and opacity was the only attribute which had not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can set width and height to 0px in print media CSS instead

```
//applies only for print media
#tawkchat-iframe-container { width:0, height:0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a hack but if nothing else works for you try this (you could isolate the css to only hide iframes in a certain container too):

```
@media print {

    iframe {
        display: none!important;
    }

}
```

Comment: This will hide all the iframe on that page.
You can use the code from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420905/style-the-tawk-to-chat-widget-with-my-custom-css/68420906#68420906 and customize as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

The following hides the widget prior to print then returns the widget after printing. The page is captured for print well before the widget is re-shown even if the user holds the print dialog open. From here: [feedback Tawk](http://feedback.tawk.to/forums/228427-feedback/suggestions/8192805-hide-window-from-print-view-on-page)

```
window.onbeforeprint = function () {
    if (Tawk_API) {
        Tawk_API.hideWidget();
        setTimeout( function(){
        Tawk_API.showWidget();
        }, 1000 );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that the widget minimizes on load, note the setTimeout is important to achieve this. It's always good to stick with the tawk to API.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
  var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async = true;
    s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/5b161b708859f57bdc7bd84d/default';
    s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);

//here's all you need
Tawk_API.onLoad = function() {
setTimeout(function() {
      Tawk_API.minimize();
    }, 1);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing some css issue and I am able to figure out on how we can override their default css with our custom css. This might help you a little bit.

[Style the Tawk.to chat widget with my custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420905/style-the-tawk-to-chat-widget-with-my-custom-css/68420906#68420906)